# k value of a matrix that has one real eigenvalue of mult. 2

Tags: linear-algebra

> For which value of $k$ does the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}-3&k\\9&4\end{bmatrix}$$ have one real eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$?

I tried finding the characteristic polynomial such that $-12 -9k-3x+x^2$
Then I did the discriminate of the polynomial to solve for $k$ and got $ k = \frac{49}{36}$ 
but that is wrong apparently and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, the characteristic polynomial is the determinant of $A-xI,$ which is $$(-3-x)(4-x)-(k)(9)=-12+3x-4x+x^2-9k=x^2+(-1)x+(-12-9k).$$ There is the first place you went off-course. The next was (possibly) in calculating the discriminant of the polynomial you found, but without seeing your work, it's hard to say how you came by a $k$-value that doesn't fit with the characteristic polynomial you found--which should have been $-\frac{19}{12}$.

Now, to have a double-root, we need the discriminant to be equal to $0,$ and as long as the coefficients are all real (as in this case), we're guaranteed that said double-root is going to be real. So, we need $$b^2-4ac=0,$$ or equivalently, $$b^2=4ac.$$ Since $a=1,$ $b=-1,$ and $c=-12-9k,$ then we need $$1=-48-36k,$$ so that $$49=-36k,$$ so that $$k=-\frac{49}{36}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is 
$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x+3 & -k \\ -9 & x-4\end{vmatrix}=x^2-x-12-9k$$
$\det(xI-A)=0$ has a repeated root when the discriminant of this quadratic is zero, i.e. when 
$$1+4(9k+12)=0 \Longleftrightarrow k=-\frac{49}{36}$$
When $k=-49/36$, the only eigenvalue is $1/2$ (with multiplicity $2$).

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalue(s) of the matrix are the roots of the polynomial $(-3-x)(4-x)-9k = x^2 -x -12-9k$, that as you can see it is different from the one you've calculated.

Now to find the value of $k$ for which this parabola has only one zero you need to set the descriminant to zero, this means $\Delta = 36k+49=0 \iff k = -\dfrac{36}{49}$.